# mat-list in angular 5

Tags: html, angular

I have a question about implement mat-list in angular 5.

I had this code, when I had the divider insede the mat-list-item but the divider line didn't show always

```html
<mat-list >
   <mat-list-item class="pathitem" *ngFor="let item of Lst" style="height: 76px;">
<div>
<h3>item.title</h3>
<p>item.desc</p>
<p>item.ad</p>
</div>
<mat-divider class="background-divider"></mat-divider>
        </mat-list-item>
      </mat-list>
```

then I change that for this:

```html
<mat-list *ngFor="let item of LstTramosFiltro" >
          <mat-list-item class="pathitem" style="height: 76px;">
<div>
<h3>item.title</h3>
<p>item.desc</p>
<p>item.ad</p>
</div>
        </mat-list-item>
<mat-divider class="background-divider"></mat-divider>
      </mat-list>
```

My question is which of the two is the correct solution if you use ngfor in mat-list or use in mat-list-item; and where the use of the mat-divider is correct

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First, ngfor should be placed in the mat-list-item instead of mat-list, otherwise you will get multiple list and each have multiple mat-list-item, and if you have multiple sections you can use mat-divider to divide into different sections, the mat-divider should be placed between two mat-list-item not inside the mat-list-item. Check https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview#lists-with-multiple-sections for details.

Answer (score 0):

the first one is current. The item you need to iterate over is the one that should have ngFor. If you want to include the divider, you may wrap both items into ng-template like this:

```
<mat-list>
    <ng-template *ngFor="let item of LstTramosFiltro">
        <mat-list-item class="pathitem" style="height: 76px;">
            <div>
                <h3>item.title</h3>
                <p>item.desc</p>
                <p>item.ad</p>
            </div>
            </mat-list-item>
        <mat-divider class="background-divider"></mat-divider>
    </ng-template>
</mat-list>
```

Comment: This wont render anything (ng-template just defines a template). I think you meant to use ng-container maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ngFor for the `mat-list-item`, not `mat-list`, assuming you only want to display a single list of items.

Doc references: https://material.angular.io/components/list/examples, https://material.angular.io/components/divider/overview

If you want the divider to show after every item except the last, it can be inserted as part of the `mat-list-item` (which I think you did), like so:

```html
<mat-list>
    <mat-list-item class="pathitem" *ngFor="let item of Lst; last as last" style="height: 76px;">
        <h3>item.title</h3>
        <p>item.desc</p>
        <p>item.ad</p>
        <mat-divider class="background-divider" *ngIf="!last"></mat-divider>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```